# generate xml file in joomla

Tags: php, xml, joomla

i'm new in joomla development coming with skills in FED development and make the first steps into server side world

i use to development with joomla and i have a problem

i need to generate xml file from php foreach argument

means i have some template in joomla with foreach to few article and i need to make from anyone of them xml row and write it to new xml file in joomla file system.

i spent allot of time to find some answer to my question and got in joomla! documentation this  [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Generating_XML_output) is explain how to make the parse but not how to make the file, this part is missing to me and i need help

if can anyone help please?

thanks allot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JFile for that. Check this out:

```
$fileName = 'path/to/file.txt';
$buffer = 'nafu';

if( JFile::write($fileName, $buffer) )
{
   echo 'File was written';
}
```

http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JFile/write

Comment: thanks mike. i'll check it. just to know is make me new file?